# How can I skip a field for json.Marshal & not for json.Unmarshal in go?

Tags: json, go, go-gorm, golang-migrate, google-app-engine-golang

```
type Alpha struct { 
  Name            string `json:"name"`
  SkipWhenMarshal string `json:"skipWhenMarshal"`
}

func MarshalJSON(out interface{}){
  json.Marshal(out)
}
```

Is it possible to ignore the **SkipWhenMarshal** field when I do **json.Marshal** but not when I do
**json.Unmarshal**.
It should work for any type who calls **MarshalJSON**

Comment: I would use reflection with a custom marshal function. added an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Field tag modifiers like "omitempty" and "-" apply to both marshaling and unmarshaling, so there's no automatic way.

You can implement a `MarshalJSON` for your type that ignores whatever fields you need. There's no need to implement a custom unmarshaler, because the default works for you.

E.g. something like this:

```
type Alpha struct {
    Id              int32
    Name            string
    SkipWhenMarshal string
}

func (a Alpha) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    m := map[string]string{
        "id":   fmt.Sprintf("%d", a.Id),
        "name": a.Name,
        // SkipWhenMarshal *not* marshaled here
    }

    return json.Marshal(m)
}
```

You can also make it simpler by using an alias type:

```
func (a Alpha) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    type AA Alpha
    aa := AA(a)
    aa.SkipWhenMarshal = ""

    return json.Marshal(aa)
}
```

Here `SkipWhenMarshal` will be output, but its value is zeroed out. The advantage in this approach is that if `Alpha` has many fields, you don't have to repeat them.

Comment: I need something that can be used in general. I am working with a lot of types that face this problem!

Comment: @NiranjanShetty: I'm not aware of a built-in options to do this. Adding some more details to the answer

Comment: Why would you want to import something from json, but not translate it back to json?

Comment: do you mean something like func MarshalJSON(out interface{}, fieldsTobeIgnored ..interface{}){} 
can you improve the function if so?

Comment: @ChenA. I have an object field & and id field, object already has id so I don't wish to send it again!

Comment: So there is no other way than defining it like that for each type?
I have 100s of types :( 
Would you say it's terrible to repeat the field value in JSON response?

Comment: @NiranjanShetty: no built-in way, but see my update with an approach that has less repetitive code

Comment: @EliBendersky why do you have to define a special type AA, and without it, it doesn't work?

Comment: @ChenA.: infinite recursion with `Alpha.MarshalJSON` calling itself

Comment: This is nice, but will be applicable if the field names are other than "SkipWhenMarhal"?

Answer (score 2):

What you want simply cannot be done with encoding/json.

**But** you can have two types

```
type AlphaIn struct { 
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Bar  string `json:"skipWhenMarshal"`
}

type AlphaOut struct { 
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Bar  string `json:"-"`
}
```

Use `AlphaIn` to deserialise JSON with encoding/json.Unmarshal and use `AlphaOut` to serialise a struct with encoding/json.Marshal to JSON.

Now this alone would be absolute painful to work with but: struct tags do not play a role in convertibility between types which lets you convert from AlphaIn to AlphaOut with a simple type conversion:

```
var a AlphaIn = ...
var b AlphaOut = AlphaOut(a)
```

(A saner naming scheme would be `Alpha` and `AlphaToJSON` or soemthing like this.)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this practice, wasn't sure we do this in go/go-gorm 
Besides, as you said it will be a pain to do this mid project with 300-500 structs

Answer (score 1):

If the structure member variable starts with a lower case, it will not be incuded.

Example:

```
type Alpha struct {
    Name            string `json:"name"`
    skipWhenMarshal string
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I would write a custom marshal function like so: [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/J1RHIXbbByd)

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "strings"
)

type Alpha struct {
    Name            string `json:"name"`
    SkipWhenMarshal string `json:"SkipWhenMarshal,skip"`
}

func main() {
    var a Alpha
    a.Name = "John"
    a.SkipWhenMarshal = "Snow"

    out, _ := marshal(a)

    fmt.Println(string(out))

    var b Alpha
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"Name":"Samwell","SkipWhenMarshal":"Tarly"}`), &b)

    fmt.Println(b)
}

// custom marshaling function for json that accepts an additional tag named skip to ignore the field
func marshal(v Alpha) ([]byte, error) {
    m := map[string]interface{}{}

    ut := reflect.TypeOf(v)
    uv := reflect.ValueOf(v)

    for i := 0; i < ut.NumField(); i++ {
        field := ut.Field(i)
        js, ok := field.Tag.Lookup("json")
        if !ok || !strings.Contains(js, "skip") {
            intf := uv.Field(i).Interface()
            switch val := intf.(type) {
            case int, int8, uint8:
                m[field.Name] = val
            case string:
                m[field.Name] = val
            }

        }
    }

    return json.Marshal(m)
}
```

It basically rebuilds the struct as a map without the *skipped* fields and passes it to the original Marshal function.

Now just add the SKIP tag to any field and it should work.

You just need to improve this part:

```
switch val := intf.(type) {
```

Since this only assumes you only have strings or ints as fields. Handling more types would be more ideal.

Comment: Unfortunately, as you're discovering with your edits, to make a really robust function you'll end up having to rewrite much of `json.Marshal` eventually :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this i.e. breaking the structure into components -> composition

while unmarshalling use Beta type. It will unmarshall only fields that are defined inside Beta struct

```
type Beta struct {
  Name            string `json:"name"`
}

type Alpha struct {
    *Beta
    SkipWhenMarshal string `json:"skipWhenMarshal"`
}
```